# Sometimes I'd like a heavier \dot

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

Sometimes I have a mathematical formula using, e.g.,  `\dot{x}` in a footnote but I have difficulties in recognizing the effective presence of a dotted variable (my fault, I know... to quote the poet "That's not the electric light, my friend\\That's your vision growing dim.").

Anyway, is it possible to use a heavier symbol for the dot that is usually used to indicate derivation w.r.t. time when used in a footnote?

Comment: @sporc Yes... In my defense, it was not in the list of similar questions... but I haven't googled in advance.

Comment: I have to say that Steven's answer, below, is better than the answers  to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED to apply italic correction to the dot placement.

```
\documentclass{arlticle}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\nsdot[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \stackengine{1.2pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\kern.3pt\normalsize .}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\newcommand\lgdot[1]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \stackengine{1.2pt}{\copy0}{\kern.2\ht0\kern.3pt\large .}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\begin{document}
\footnote{Here is the normal $\dot x$ and now 
  \nsdot{x} and here is
  \lgdot{x}\\
  Also, \nsdot{x}, \nsdot{k}, \nsdot{P}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely useful.

Comment: ... and  `\nsddot` is just `{\kern.2\ht0\kern.3pt\normalsize ..}` or there is a detail that I'm missing?

Comment: @gboffi yes, though you may need to alter the `.3pt` to a slightly smaller value to get proper horizontal centering.  Also, if the space *between* the dots is not to your liking, you could add a positive or negative kern between the dots, as well.

Comment: You may want to post your answer also in the question this is a duplicate of.  In my opinion, it is better than the other answers.

Comment: The fact that this was closed as a duplicate will mean that, in that question, this one will be listed under "Linked" questions (see right margin).  Thus, someone at that question can easily follow the trail to this one.  But thanks for thinking of me.  If you wanted, you could also post this link as a comment to the question.